# Web Speech API text-to-speech : How to have one JavaScript code that works for several texts to be read?

Tags: javascript, php, text-to-speech

Is it possible to have a single JavaScript code (with the help of PHP or something else) for all the different texts to be read instead of having a code for each text to be read as in my current code? In this example there is only 4 texts to be read but I have one web page that has around 130.

Here is the HTML code in 4 PHP different pages (I use include php to add those buttons where needed):

```
<div class="read"><button id="lectureObjectif">Écoutez</button>&nbsp<button id="pauseObjectif">Pause</button>&nbsp<button id="reprendreObjectif">Reprendre</button>&nbsp<button id="arretObjectif">Arrêtter</button></div>

<div class="read"><button id="lecturePourquoi">Écoutez</button>&nbsp<button id="pausePourquoi">Pause</button>&nbsp<button id="reprendrePourquoi">Reprendre</button>&nbsp<button id="arretPourquoi">Arrêtter</button></div>

<div class="read"><button id="lectureNouvelles">Écoutez</button>&nbsp<button id="pauseNouvelles">Pause</button>&nbsp<button id="reprendreNouvelles">Reprendre</button>&nbsp<button id="arretNouvelles">Arrêtter</button></div>

<div class="read"><button id="lectureDissonance">Écoutez</button>&nbsp<button id="pauseDissonance">Pause</button>&nbsp<button id="reprendreDissonance">Reprendre</button>&nbsp<button id="arretDissonance">Arrêtter</button></div>
```

Here is the JavasCript code on 1 page (I don't want to use a third party JavaScript). I am novice in programming and very novice in JavaScript.

```
    //////////////////////////////// Obectif /////////////////////////////////////////  
    // pointer vers nos éléments
    let btnLectureObjectif = document.getElementById("lectureObjectif");
    let btnPauseObjectif = document.getElementById("pauseObjectif");
    let btnReprendreObjectif = document.getElementById("reprendreObjectif");
    let btnArretObjectif = document.getElementById("arretObjectif");
    let divObjectif = document.getElementById("objectif");

    btnArretObjectif.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }
    btnLectureObjectif.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
        /*let texte = "Coucou";*/
        let texteObjectif = divObjectif.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.lang = 'fr-Fr'; // language, default is 'en-US'
        parole.text = texteObjectif;
        parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
        parole.rate = 1.3; // 0.1 à 10 = vitesse
        parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
        // fair parler
        speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
    }
    btnPauseObjectif.onclick = function () {
        let texteObjectif = divObjectif.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteObjectif;
        // fair une pause
        speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
    }
    btnReprendreObjectif.onclick = function () {
        let texteObjectif = divObjectif.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteObjectif;
        // reprendre la lecture
        speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
    }

    ////////////////////////////// Pourquoi ///////////////////////////////////////////     
    // pointer vers nos éléments
    let btnLecturePourquoi = document.getElementById("lecturePourquoi");
    let btnPausePourquoi = document.getElementById("pausePourquoi");
    let btnReprendrePourquoi = document.getElementById("reprendrePourquoi");
    let btnArretPourquoi = document.getElementById("arretPourquoi");
    let divPourquoi = document.getElementById("pourquoi");

    btnArretPourquoi.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }
    btnLecturePourquoi.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
        /*let texte = "Coucou";*/
        let textePourquoi = divPourquoi.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = textePourquoi;
        parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
        parole.rate = 1; // 0.5 à 2 = vitesse
        parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
        // fair parler
        speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
    }
    btnPausePourquoi.onclick = function () {
        let textePourquoi = divPourquoi.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = textePourquoi;
        // fair une pause
        speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
    }
    btnReprendrePourquoi.onclick = function () {
        let textePourquoi = divPourquoi.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = textePourquoi;
        // reprendre la lecture
        speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
    }

    //////////////////////////////// Nouvelles /////////////////////////////////////////        
    // pointer vers nos éléments
    let btnLectureNouvelles = document.getElementById("lectureNouvelles");
    let btnPauseNouvelles = document.getElementById("pauseNouvelles");
    let btnReprendreNouvelles = document.getElementById("reprendreNouvelles");
    let btnArretNouvelles = document.getElementById("arretNouvelles");
    let divNouvelles = document.getElementById("nouvelles");

    btnArretNouvelles.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }
    btnLectureNouvelles.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
        /*let texte = "Coucou";*/
        let texteNouvelles = divNouvelles.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteNouvelles;
        parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
        parole.rate = 1; // 0.5 à 2 = vitesse
        parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
        // fair parler
        speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
    }
    btnPauseNouvelles.onclick = function () {
        let texteNouvelles = divNouvelles.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteNouvelles;
        // fair une pause
        speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
    }
    btnReprendreNouvelles.onclick = function () {
            let texteNouvelles = divNouvelles.textContent;
            // instancier un objet d'énonciation
            let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            parole.text = texteNouvelles;
            // reprendre la lecture
            speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
        }
        ////////////////////////// Dissonance ////////////////////////////////
        // pointer vers nos éléments
    let btnLectureDissonance = document.getElementById("lectureDissonance");
    let btnPauseDissonance = document.getElementById("pauseDissonance");
    let btnReprendreDissonance = document.getElementById("reprendreDissonance");
    let btnArretDissonance = document.getElementById("arretDissonance");
    let divDissonance = document.getElementById("dissonance");

    btnArretDissonance.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }
    btnLectureDissonance.onclick = function () {
        speechSynthesis.cancel();
        /*let texte = "Coucou";*/
        let texteDissonance = divDissonance.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteDissonance;
        parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
        parole.rate = 1; // 0.5 à 2 = vitesse
        parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
        // fair parler
        speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
    }
    btnPauseDissonance.onclick = function () {
        let texteDissonance = divDissonance.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteDissonance;
        // fair une pause
        speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
    }
    btnReprendreDissonance.onclick = function () {
        let texteDissonance = divDissonance.textContent;
        // instancier un objet d'énonciation
        let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        parole.text = texteDissonance;
        // reprendre la lecture
        speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible: By serious re-factoring your *explicit* code. Basically, you need to *abstract*, ie.  generate the variations based on the common patterns you've identified. I won't write all that code for you, however here's a walk-through with a generous serving of examples.

First, let's take the code apart; looking at just one of many repetitions. Below, we're sampling the necessary code for a single text, with the text name replaced with a `{{ TEXTNAME }}` placeholder to help you see what all is being duplicated. For each text, you have HTML buttons as follows:

```
<button id="lecture{{ TEXTNAME }}">Écoutez</button>
<button id="pause{{ TEXTNAME }}">Pause</button>
<button id="reprendre{{ TEXTNAME }}">Reprendre</button>
<button id="arret{{ TEXTNAME }}">Arrêtter</button>
```

Then, you have JavaScript as follows.

```
/* You don't really need the following five "let"s. 
   Get the relevant DOM objects inside the functions. */

let btnLecturet{{ TEXTNAME }} = document.getElementById("lecture{{ TEXTNAME }}");
let btnPause{{ TEXTNAME }} = document.getElementById("pause{{ TEXTNAME }}");
let btnReprendre{{ TEXTNAME }} = document.getElementById("reprendre{{ TEXTNAME }}");
let btnArret{{ TEXTNAME }} = document.getElementById("arret{{ TEXTNAME }}");
let div{{ TEXTNAME }} = document.getElementById("{{ TEXTNAME }}");

/* Here we have four *explicit* functions that are 
   unnecessarily repeated for each event handler definition: */

btnArret{{ TEXTNAME }}.onclick = function () {
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
}
btnLecture{{ TEXTNAME }}.onclick = function () {
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
    /*let texte = "Coucou";*/
    let texte{{ TEXTNAME }} = div{{ TEXTNAME }}.textContent;
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    parole.lang = 'fr-Fr'; // language, default is 'en-US'
    parole.text = texte{{ TEXTNAME }};
    parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
    parole.rate = 1.3; // 0.1 à 10 = vitesse
    parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
    // fair parler
    speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
}
btnPause{{ TEXTNAME }}.onclick = function () {
    let texte{{ TEXTNAME }} = div{{ TEXTNAME }}.textContent;
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    parole.text = texte{{ TEXTNAME }};
    // fair une pause
    speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
}
btnReprendre{{ TEXTNAME }}.onclick = function () {
    let texte{{ TEXTNAME }} = div{{ TEXTNAME }}.textContent;
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    parole.text = texte{{ TEXTNAME }};
    // reprendre la lecture
    speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
}
```

You will notice that the Javascript functions above contain unnecessary explicit information ("TEXTNAME"). This makes them non-reusable. It'd be fine to do that if you had one or two fixed implementations only; but you have lots, and you want to update things easily.

*Now, the cool thing about functions: they can take arguments that qualify their action or return value, allowing you to re-use the same code for any number of variant cases.* Suppose you did the following instead (for an example, you'd do a similar "generalization" for the remaining functions):

```
function doPause(textName) {
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    /* simply get the DOM object right here: */
    parole.text = document.getElementById(textName).textContent;
    // fair une pause
    speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
}
```

Then, we have a *generic pause-action function that takes the text's name/identifier as an argument*, which can be applied to any number of cases (example below follows your old code):

```
btnPauseWHATEVERTEXT.onclick = doPause("WHATEVERTEXT");
btnPauseQUESTCEQUECEST.onclick = doPause("QUESTCEQUECEST");
```

That's already much more manageable, right? You'd only need to declare one set of functions: `doArret(textName)`, `doLecture(textName)`, `doPause(textName)`, and `doReprendre(textName)`.

Then, all that remains is spelling out the buttons and the event handlers. Now, switching to PHP. Suppose you had the following function:

```
function make_buttons($textname) {
    $buttons = [];
    $buttons[] = '<button id="lecture' . $textname . '">Écoutez</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="pause' . $textname . '">Pause</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="reprendre' . $textname . '">Écoutez</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="arret' . $textname . '">Arrêtter</button>';
    return implode("&nbsp;", $buttons);
}
```

You'd have your little "button factory" right there. And then you could have another generic function that deals with making button event handler sets:

```
function make_events($textname) {
    $clicks = [];
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('lecture{$textname}').onclick = doLecture('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('pause{$textname}').onclick = doPause('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('reprendre{$textname}').onclick = doReprendre('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('arret{$textname}').onclick = doArret('{$textname}');";
    return implode("\n", $clicks);
}
```

This would give you the JS code for creating the on-clicks for a given text. Now, all you need to do is put it all together, with something like this (again with PHP):

```
$texts = ['Objectif', 'Subjectif', 'Reflectif', 'Asterix', 'Obelix'];

$buttons = [];
$events = [];

foreach($texts as $text) {
    $buttons[$text] = make_buttons($text);
    $events[$text] = make_events($text);
}

// If you want to flatten the $buttons array into a string,
// do this; and put $buttons to wherever all the buttons go
$buttons = implode("\n", $buttons); 

// or otherwise, you can get a particular text's buttons like this:
echo "<div>Voici les buttons pour text Reflectif: {$buttons['Reflectif']}</div>";

// and put the events where your JS is, after the generic "doStuff()" functions
$events = implode("\n", $events);
```

With the above measures, you can spare yourself from a lot of unnecessary repetition. Let's recap:

1. Clean up your explicit JS functions into *generic* functions (with an argument) that can be assigned to onclick-events;
2. Create PHP functions that generate the buttons and the event handlers.
3. Loop through your text names for a given page using these functions; and put the HTML and the JS where they belong.
4. Spend more time pondering and learning how you can *abstract* and *reuse* your code.

There are certainly other ways of handling this. You could generate more with JS only at client-end, for example. Since you're just getting started with programming, this is more of a simple and educational refactoring; not the final word in slick and optimized; but it should make your life a fair bit easier. Happy homeworks, let us know how your code evolves! `=(^o^)=`

Comment: Thanks, Markus, for you help. :) You convinced me to learn some js and PHP. I'll watch some Video lessons and read som tutorials. With that, I'll see more clearly your precious explanation and codes. It might take few days, but I'll be back here to show my evolution.

Comment: If you intend to work on project websites, picking up some useful basics in PHP and JS goes a long way in improving the quality of your experience (and your projects). Enjoy the process!

Comment: I'm just working on my (one) Website. I passed around 10 hours, watching js script video ans few hours more reading W3School js explanation. That will certainly help for future uses, if needed. For now, I understand the principle of what you wrote, but  I'm lost. I came up with my codes by trials and errors.  I cannot know if what you wrote is code or code explained. I understand what function are and the idea of having variables that will take names and become different "id"s. I'll keep researching and learn more.

Comment: Good to hear you're keen to dig in. What I gave you above is actually 80+% ready to plug in and use. You'd simply have to come up with `doLecture`, `doReprendre` and `doArret` functions, following the model of `doPause` above. And then put all the PHP code into `.php` files; one file for the functions (that you `require` in files with implementation details), and how-so-ever-many files for your specific audios.

Comment: I appreciate your help. My head is burning, but I'm starting to understand your code. :)

Comment: Head burning is the first symptom of actual code evolution looming. Keep on at it, and remember to drink enough!

Comment: I am blocked. I tried to use Firefox developer tools (console, debugger), but there are no errors displayed. What step, what should I read in order to move forward. I drink water (hehehe) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I'm at:
Things are starting to take shape but the reading is no happening.

I just use, for this exercise, one PHP file :

```
<body>
<?php 
    
    //  "id"s  of the "div"s to be spoken
$texts = ['Objectif', 'Pourquoi'];
    
    
$buttons = [];
$events = [];

foreach($texts as $text) {
    $buttons[$text] = make_buttons($text);
    $events[$text] = make_events($text);
}
    
    function make_buttons($textname) {
    $buttons = [];
    $buttons[] = '<button id="lecture' . $textname . '">Écouter</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="pause' . $textname . '">Pause</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="reprendre' . $textname . '">Reprendre</button>';
    $buttons[] = '<button id="arret' . $textname . '">Arrêtter</button>';
    return implode("&nbsp;", $buttons);
    
}
    function make_events($textname) {
    $clicks = [];
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('lecture{$textname}').onclick = doLecture('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('pause{$textname}').onclick = doPause('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('reprendre{$textname}').onclick = doReprendre('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('arret{$textname}').onclick = doArret('{$textname}');";
    return implode("\n", $clicks);
}   
        
    ?>
    
    <?php   // Show buttons for the div with the id Objectif to be spoken
    echo "<div>{$buttons['Objectif']}</div>";?>

    <!-- The div (with the Objectif id) to be spoken -->
    <div id="Objectif" class="moi-wrap-text">
        <p>L'objectif de ce site est important. </p>
    </div>

    <?php   // Show buttons for the div with the id Pourquoi to be spoken
    echo "<div>{$buttons['Pourquoi']}</div>";?>

    <!-- The div (with the Pourquoi id) to be spoken -->
    <div id="Pourquoi" class="moi-wrap-text">
        <p>Pourquoi est-il important de savoir?</p>
    </div>

    <!-- External JavaScript file -->
    <script src="scrypte.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

And here is my JavaScript file

```
// Function for Speak
function doLecture(textName) {
    /* Removes all utterances from the utterance queue and
    if an utterance is currently being spoken, speaking will stop */
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    parole.lang = 'fr-Fr'; // language, default is 'en-US'
    parole.pitch = 1; // 0 à 2 = hauteur
    parole.rate = 1.3; // 0.1 à 10 = vitesse
    parole.volume = 1; // 0 à 1 = volume
    // Get the DOM object
    parole.text = document.getElementById(textName).textContent;
    // Speak
    speechSynthesis.speak(parole);
}

// Function for Pause
function doPause(textName) {
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    // Get the DOM object
    parole.text = document.getElementById(textName).textContent;
    // Pause speaking
    speechSynthesis.pause(parole);
}

// Function for Resume
function doReprendre(textName) {
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    // Get the DOM object
    parole.text = document.getElementById(textName).textContent;
    // Resume speaking
    speechSynthesis.resume(parole);
}

// Function for Stop
function doArret(textName) {
    // instancier un objet d'énonciation
    let parole = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    // Get the DOM object
    parole.text = document.getElementById(textName).textContent;
    // Stop speaking
    speechSynthesis.stop(parole);
}

$events = implode("\n", $events);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to make it worked (except for my mobile phone browsers).

I had to replace this code:

```
    function make_events($textname) {
    $clicks = [];
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('lecture{$textname}').onclick = doLecture('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('pause{$textname}').onclick = doPause('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('reprendre{$textname}').onclick = doReprendre('{$textname}');";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('arret{$textname}').onclick = doArret('{$textname}');";
    return implode("\n", $clicks);
}
```

By this code:

```
function make_events( $textname ) {
    $clicks = [];
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('lecture{$textname}').onclick = function(){doLecture('{$textname}');};";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('pause{$textname}').onclick = function(){doPause('{$textname}');};";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('reprendre{$textname}').onclick = function(){doReprendre('{$textname}');};";
    $clicks[] = "document.getElementById('arret{$textname}').onclick = function(){doArret('{$textname}');};";
    return implode( "\n", $clicks );
}
```

Thanks, again, Markus AO for your help.

But, again, this doesn't work (or work properly) in my mobile phone browsers.
In some browser I can make speak, for instance, the first text and than stop it, but the other text are not playable. For all browsers the Pause and Resume don't work at all.